# How could I confirm if my server supports hole punching?

Tags: linux, ext4

I want to use MySQL 5.7's [page compression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-page-compression.html) feature, but this feature requires Linux's hole punching feature, and according to the documentation, this was introduced in 2.6.39. But my server's kernel version is 2.6.32, and I verified the page compression feature does work there, it's strange!
So I want to be sure whether my server supports this hole punch feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test it by punching a hole yourself.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=punch bs=100M count=1
```

creates a 100MiB file, with no holes, as can be checked with `du`:

```
$ du -h punch
100M    punch
```

Now punch a 10MiB hole in it:

```
$ fallocate -p -o 2M -l 10M punch
```

The file’s size won’t change (as indicated by `ls -lh`), but it will take less space on disk if your kernel and file system support the necessary system calls:

```
$ du -h punch
90M     punch
```

`man fallocate` will tell you more; your 2.6.32-based system might well have a kernel where the relevant support has been back-ported.